# jQuery UI - Slider MIN value don't work for values from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem is pretty simple but very annoying here is code that work:

```
var minPriceString = $( "#minimalPrice" ).val();
var minPriceFloat = parseFloat(minPriceString).toFixed(0);

var maxPriceString = $( "#maxPrice" ).text().replace('PLN', '').replace(',', '');
var maxPriceFloat = parseFloat(maxPriceString).toFixed(0);

$("#slider-range").slider(
{
            value:100,
            min: 30,
            max: maxPriceFloat,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2093/

As you can see the max value of slider is taken from DOM object and parse to float (all works fine). But when I want to take min value in the same way slider just STUCK here is code:

```
var minPriceString = $( "#minimalPrice" ).val();
var minPriceFloat = parseFloat(minPriceString).toFixed(0);

var maxPriceString = $( "#maxPrice" ).text().replace('PLN', '').replace(',', '');
var maxPriceFloat = parseFloat(maxPriceString).toFixed(0);

$("#slider-range").slider(
{
            value:100,
            min: minPriceFloat,
            max: maxPriceFloat,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2092/

What I'm doing wrong or maybe its a bug ?

Comment: have you checked logging the value of minPriceString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var minPriceString = $("#minimalPrice").text();
var minPriceFloat = parseFloat(minPriceString);

var maxPriceString = $("#maxPrice").text();
var maxPriceFloat = parseFloat(maxPriceString);

$("#slider-range").slider({
    value: 100,
    min: minPriceFloat,
    max: maxPriceFloat,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#slider-value").html(ui.value);
    }
});

$("#slider-value").html($('#slider').slider('value'));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/5TTm4/2095/)